# What "Gotchas" are should I look out for migrating from VS Pro to VSTS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I recently got a copy of Visual Studio Team System Suite 2008. I am currently running Visual Studio Professional 2008.  I am sure others have done this migration in the past.

What problems, if any, did you encounter?

Should I first uninstall Pro?

What about existing add-ons, Code Rush, GhostDoc etc?  Do I need to uninstall these?  Will I need to reinstall in order to use them with Team System?

I would love to hear about any experiences you have had both good and bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We made the switch and encountered absolutely no problems.  Well,  the installation for the Team Foundation Server was a royal pain, but that's not what you asked about.  As far as Visual Studio goes, no issues whatsoever.

You should uninstall the pro version first.

As for add-ons, I don't know for sure because we never used them, but I would assume that you would uninstall those, install VSTS, then reinstall the add-ins.

Comment: One can install the team editions over Pro, they will end up as one, enabling the features of both.